# Finding greatest sum of difference between integers that meet a certain condition

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a list of 1,000,000 integers. Each integer is smaller than or equal to 100,000.

I have to find the greatest sum of the difference between integers where the first integer is smaller than the second, and the second integer is larger than the third. The third integer is allowed to be smaller OR larger than the first. Furthermore, the first integer has to be located before the second, and the second integer has to be located before the third.

My algorithm for solving this is as follows:

1) Run the list provided through a loop.

2) Pick the largest integer after the current integer that is read.

3) Find the difference between this and the current integer.

4) Pick the smallest integer located after the integer in part (2). Find the difference between this integer and the integer found in part (2).

5) Add this to the integer found in part (3) and store this value as the current highest.

6) Repeat this process and replace the current highest as necessary.

However, my algorithm for solving this fails the time constraints (1 second per test case). It's also incorrect for a few test cases. I'm using C++ for your information.

An example is provided below.

Input:
60
70
30
50
40
60
20
10

Output: 80

Explanation: The third, sixth and eighth integers in the list satisfy the condition best.

**My Question:** What's the best (fastest) way to solve this problem?

Comment: @MattMcNabb It asks for the greatest differences between integers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Good point. Title and body has now been edited accordingly.

Comment: Is speed the question, or is the algorithm the question? What hardware? How many cores? There are other ways to attain speed than algorithms.

Comment: @AviGinsburg An efficient algorithm is what I'm after; one that can do the job. For your information, the program will be tested on Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.00GHz and g++ version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8) (using -m32 -O2 -lm).

Comment: @Cloud can you explain why my solution with 90 is invalid

Comment: @MattMcNabb Which integers did you use?

Comment: @MattMcNabb The first integer you choose must be located before the second. And the third integer you choose must be located after the second.

Comment: You wrote an O(n^2) algorithm.  To get it to finish within 1 second, you need to go shopping for a computer with a cycle time less than one picosecond.  Unlikely to fit your budget.  This homework assignment was created to force you to come up with an algorithm that is less than O(n^2).  Hopefully nobody here will stop you from thinking about it, that would be dreadful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem with current approach

Your current algorithm is not quite correct, consider the sequence:

```
1,99,1,100,99
```

Your current algorithm will pick the following cases (the different cases correspond to different starting locations):

```
1,100,99 score 100
99,100,99 score 2
1,100,99 score 100
```

however, the best choice is 1,99,1 for a score of 98*2=196

Also the complexity is O(n^2) which will be too slow.

### Better algorithm

A O(n) approach to this is to compute an array A[n] which gives the smallest value in the range 0,1,..,n-1, and an array B[n] which gives the smallest value in the range n+1,n+2,..,end.

You can compute these in O(n) by working forwards through the array to make A, and backwards to make B.

Once you have these, you can make a third pass through the array.  For each index i, you choose A[i] for the first element, i for the middle element, B[i] for the third element.

You work out the score for this combination and keep the best one.

(You can also combine a couple of these passes for a slightly more complicated but potentially more efficient solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you picking three consecutive integers from the list?

If not, then clearly sorting the list and picking smallest, largest, smallest is always the winner?

If you have to use three consecutive integers from the list, then you really have no choice but to process the list sequentially working out the differences and holding onto the biggest?

I interpret this problem to mean that you must pick three integers where A,B,C appear in that order in the list, but are not necessarily consecutive, is that correct?

If so, imagine splitting your list up into N subsequences of M numbers. For each subsequence find the largest and smallest number.

Then use these to pick the best sequence of smallest, largest, smallest, or largest smallest largest.

As long as every pick is in a different subsequence then you are done. If two of the numbers happen to be in the same subsequence, then you need to check that they appear in the correct order. If they do not, discard that solution and choose the next best.

I would suggest that probably choosing subsequence size of about 1000 elements will give you a very low probability of two numbers being in the same sequence, and still reduce the comparisons by a lot.

==============

Alternative answer

Suppose that we have two consecutive subsequence of ten numbers, and you work out the best ABC in each, then I have two ABC sequences, and I can easily combine them, there are only a few ways to combine these sequences, and one of the combinations must be the best for the twenty element list.

You can then build this up dynamic style.